# Add vertical line in a DT datatable in a shiny app with custom container

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I want to add a vertical line between groups of columns. Here is a desired outcome:

```
---------
g1  | g2
---------
a b | a b
---------
1 2 | 3 4
---------
```

and a shiny app to start with:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui <- basicPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput('table1')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(data.frame(a1 = 1, b1 = 2, a2 = 3, b2 = 4), rownames = FALSE,
                container = withTags(table(
                  class = 'display',
                  thead(
                    tr(
                      th(colspan = 2, 'g1'),
                      th(colspan = 2, 'g2')
                    ),
                    tr(
                      lapply(rep(c('a', 'b'), 2), th)
                    )
                  )
                ))
      )
    })
  }
))
```

Current output from shiny app above:

[image]

Comment: Might help: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html

Comment: How this might help? This does not tell anything about column grouping.

Comment: Closest extension which I found. It seems that you have to write javascript so example how to do row grouping might help.

Comment: I would look at this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56142354/how-can-i-add-a-vertical-line-to-a-datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56142354/how-can-i-add-a-vertical-line-to-a-datatable)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could add a css class that adds a border on the right of the cells and apply it to the relevant columns using the `columnDefs` options. For the header, you can set the class using the `initComplete` callback.

Here's an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui <- basicPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML(".cell-border-right{border-right: 1px solid #000}"))),
    DT::dataTableOutput('table1')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(data.frame(a1 = 1, b1 = 2, a2 = 3, b2 = 4), rownames = FALSE,
                container = withTags(table(
                  class = 'display',
                  thead(
                    tr(
                      th(colspan = 2, 'g1'),
                      th(colspan = 2, 'g2')
                    ),
                    tr(
                      lapply(rep(c('a', 'b'), 2), th)
                    )
                  )
                )),options = list(initComplete = JS(
                  "function(settings, json) {",
                  "var headerBorder = [0,1];",
                  "var header = $(this.api().table().header()).find('tr:first > th').filter(function(index) {return $.inArray(index,headerBorder) > -1 ;}).addClass('cell-border-right');",
                  "}"),columnDefs=list(list(className="dt-right cell-border-right",targets=1))
      ))
    })
  }
))
```

The `jquery` selectors are used to select the first row of the header and the first `th` tag, so that the border is only added to the `g1` cell.

Comment: Thank you @NicE for the answer. Could you show how can I add the line in the header row for any columns using indexes (like using `targets` for the table body)?

Comment: Sure, you can replace `th:first` by `th:eq(1)` and change the number in the `eq`, it's a `jquery selector`, more info [here](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Comment: And what about several columns (like targets = c(0, 1))? Thanks.

Comment: I edited for this, you can use the `jquery` `filter` function, here it goes through the `th` cells of the header and adds a border if they are in the `headerBorder` array. You can probably build the `headerBorder` array using `paste` if the columns you want a border for a stored in an R vector.