# How to add a vertical line to the first column header in a data table?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, dt

I would like to add a vertical line to a DT table column header. There is guidance for adding this line in post [How can I add a vertical line to a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56142354/how-can-i-add-a-vertical-line-to-a-datatable), but it applies to a static table where columns are manually set whereas in my MWE code (at bottom), the columns are set using the `lapply()` function in a reactive setting. So I'm having trouble using this guidance in my particular circumstances.

Any suggestions for adding a vertical line to the right of the left-most column header labeled "to_state"? As shown in this image which shows a portion of the output window when running the MWE code:

[image]

Please note that in the fuller code this MWE derives from, the table expands/contracts dynamically depending on the number of unique states detected in the underlying data. Therefore I can't use a static table set up like in the referenced related post above.

Once this is resolved, I'll have several additional questions as I struggle to make a transition table readily understandable for users (such as change the "to_state" left-most column header to "To end Period = [xxx]", but that will be addressed in another post). I'm tackling this formatting issue incrementally in baby steps.

I am very unfamiliar with `HTML`, `CSS`.

Here is the MWE code:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
library(data.table)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
    State = c("X0","X1","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X0")
  )

numTransit <- function(x, from=1, to=3){
  setDT(x)
  unique_state <- unique(x$State)
  all_states <- setDT(expand.grid(list(from_state = unique_state, to_state = unique_state)))
  dcast(x[, .(from_state = State[from], 
              to_state = State[to]), 
          by = ID]
        [,.N, c("from_state", "to_state")]
        [all_states,on = c("from_state", "to_state")], 
        to_state ~ from_state, value.var = "N"
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(".datatables .display {margin-left: 0;}")), # < left-align the table
  h4(strong("Base data frame:")), 
  tableOutput("data"),
  h4(strong("Transition table inputs:")),
  numericInput("transFrom", "From Period:", 1, min = 1, max = 3),
  numericInput("transTo", "To Period:", 2, min = 1, max = 3),
  h4(strong("Output transition table:")), 
  DTOutput("resultsDT"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  results <- 
    reactive({
      results <- numTransit(data, input$transFrom, input$transTo) %>% 
        replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
        bind_rows(summarise_all(., ~(if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Sum")))
      results <- cbind(results, Sum = rowSums(results[,-1]))
    })
  
  output$data <- renderTable(data)
  
  output$resultsDT <- renderDT(server=FALSE, {
    req(results())
    datatable(
      data = results(),
      rownames = FALSE,
      filter = 'none',
      container = tags$table(
        class = 'display',
        tags$thead(
          tags$tr(
            tags$th(colspan = 1, '', style = "border-right: solid 1px;"),
            tags$th(colspan = 10, sprintf('From initial Period = %s', input$transFrom))
          ),
          tags$tr(
            lapply(colnames(results()), 
                   tags$th
                   )
          ),
        )
      ),
      options = list(scrollX = F
                     , dom = 'ft'
                     , lengthChange = T
                     , pagingType = "numbers"  # hides Next and Previous buttons
                     , autoWidth = T
                     , info = FALSE #  hide the "Showing 1 of 2..." at bottom of table
                     , searching = FALSE  # removes search box
      ),
      class = "display"
    ) %>%
      formatStyle(c(1), `border-right` = "solid 1px")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mapply` instead of `lapply` to control the `style` parameter:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(htmltools)
library(data.table)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
    State = c("X0","X1","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X0")
  )

numTransit <- function(x, from=1, to=3){
  setDT(x)
  unique_state <- unique(x$State)
  all_states <- setDT(expand.grid(list(from_state = unique_state, to_state = unique_state)))
  dcast(x[, .(from_state = State[from], 
              to_state = State[to]), 
          by = ID]
        [,.N, c("from_state", "to_state")]
        [all_states,on = c("from_state", "to_state")], 
        to_state ~ from_state, value.var = "N"
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(".datatables .display {margin-left: 0;}")), # < left-align the table
  h4(strong("Base data frame:")), 
  tableOutput("data"),
  h4(strong("Transition table inputs:")),
  numericInput("transFrom", "From Period:", 1, min = 1, max = 3),
  numericInput("transTo", "To Period:", 2, min = 1, max = 3),
  h4(strong("Output transition table:")), 
  DTOutput("resultsDT"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  results <- 
    reactive({
      results <- numTransit(data, input$transFrom, input$transTo) %>% 
        replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
        bind_rows(summarise_all(., ~(if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Sum")))
      results <- cbind(results, Sum = rowSums(results[,-1]))
    })
  
  output$data <- renderTable(data)
  
  output$resultsDT <- renderDT(server=FALSE, {
    req(results())
    datatable(
      data = results(),
      rownames = FALSE,
      filter = 'none',
      container = tags$table(
        class = 'display',
        tags$thead(
          tags$tr(
            tags$th(colspan = 1, '', style = "border-right: solid 1px;"),
            tags$th(colspan = 10, sprintf('From initial Period = %s', input$transFrom))
          ),
          tags$tr(
            mapply(tags$th, colnames(results()), style = sprintf("border-right: solid %spx;", c(1L, rep(0, ncol(results())-1L))), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
            )
          )
      ),
      options = list(scrollX = F
                     , dom = 'ft'
                     , lengthChange = T
                     , pagingType = "numbers"  # hides Next and Previous buttons
                     , autoWidth = T
                     , info = FALSE #  hide the "Showing 1 of 2..." at bottom of table
                     , searching = FALSE  # removes search box
      ),
      class = "display"
    ) %>%
      formatStyle(c(1), `border-right` = "solid 1px")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]